# Como Habilitar Persistência Offline no Firestore com Vue.js

Tags: firebase, vue.js

Estou tendo um problema ao habilitar o modo de persistência offline do Firebase. Estou usando o Vue.js com Electron e meu arquivo de configuração do Firebase está da seguinte maneira:

[image: firebaseInit.js]

Está retornando este erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Espero que alguém consiga dar alguma solução. Desde já agradeço!

Comment: Isso parece ser um bug interno. Não vejo nenhum erro semelhante na internet, sugiro que você [contacte a equipa do Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/)

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes eu solucionei isso incluindo o Firebase via <script>, por enquanto. Mas é bem chato ter que usar dessa forma por causa desse Bug. Até o momento não encontrei outra solução.

Comment: Você pode postar o código da sua solução como resposta? Irá ajudar pessoas que tenham o mesmo erro.